# seem to have lost typescript debugging capabilities after cli ng build

Tags: angular

I recently restructured a nested ng2 app nested within a .NET MVC app in order to support CLI capabilities.  I did an "ng build" which seems to have worked as expected. However, it seems that I no longer have the ability to debug typescript in the browser.  My top-level tsconfig.json file still has "sourceMap": true. Any idea what the issue might be or how to debug?

Comment: Have you tried doing `ng build --dev` or `ng build --target=development --environment=dev`?

Comment: that did the trick thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run **ng build** targeting `development` by using:

`ng build --dev` or `ng build --target=development --environment=dev`

Angular cli builds for production by default which *gets rid of a bunch of development stuff* including the maps providing better performance.